# Multinomial logistic regression or ANOVA to predict percentage?

Tags: anova, categorical-data, percentage, multinomial-logit

I have several categorical predictors:

- experimental_group [A,B] # medicated/not
- factor1 [i,j] # task conditions
- factor2 [x,y] # task conditions

And I need to predict:

- **percentage of choices** of 4 categories [c1,c2,c3,c4] in N trials

My professor suggests ANOVA: **% ~ category**

But this feels wrong.
And I also want to check for factor1 & factor2

Google suggests Multinomial logistic regression.

- Should it be like this then: **% ~ exp_group + factor1 + factor2**
- or i should dummify **categories** somehow? how will the formula look then?

Data is like that:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you have as a measurement of those choices and the percentages? If you have categorical outcomes like “under these conditions (values of your predictors), the choice was dog; under these conditions, the choice was cat,” then multinomial logistic regression seems like an obvious starting point. // I’m having trouble imagining how ANOVA would apply your situation, but maybe that will become obvious once you say more about your data.

Comment: for some given values of predictors [say, group=A, f1=i, f2=x] - there will be some distribution of 100% of choices between 4 categories [say, c1=0.7, c2=0.2, c3=0.08, c4=0.02]/ per subject

Comment: How do you get that distribution? Do you have multiple subjects for that combination of predictor values?

Comment: (per subject)c1% = number of trials where  c1 was chosen  / N trials. It is 0:1 instead of 0:100 for the logit purposes

Comment: Do you have access to the number of times each choice was chosen? (If you have the percentages and the total number, you can multiple to get the raw number of each choice.)

Comment: i have the number of times, yes

Comment: Then multinomial logistic regression is an outstanding candidate! You use the observed choices to model the probability of making each choice. If you understand binary/binomial logistic regression, the jump to multinomial is fairly easy. I can’t post an answer right now, and it might be worth adding some additional information about your data in an edit to your original post, but I expect an approach based on multinomial logistic regression to work well for your task.

Comment: thank you @Dave! i added the data description

Comment: Is the outcome the number of times that a particular `strategy` is chosen? Or something else? In the data sample that you show, it seems that strategies `s1` and `s2` are only available when `factor1` is `low`, and strategies `s3` and `s4` are only available when `factor1` is `high`. If that's the case, the analysis might need to be modified from a simple multinomial regression. Also, the example data don't show values for `factor2` so we can't tell how its values might be combined with the other variables. Please edit the question to address those matters.

Comment: No, i just put it that way to shorten the representation.(1) we can ignore factor 1 for now (2) all 4 strategies are paired with all factor1 levels

Answer (score 0):

Yes, multinomial regression can be a good choice when there are more than 2 mutually exclusive outcomes. ANOVA can work when the residuals around the model predictions can come close to a normal distribution, but that's typically not the case with percentage outcomes. If there's a natural ordering to the outcomes (say, each level of `strategy` is known to the participant to be more difficult than the lower-numbered strategies), then ordinal regression would be a good choice.

This [UCLA web page](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/dae/) has links to implementation of multinomial or ordinal logistic regression in 5 software packages. See individual pages for cautions about important considerations like the Independence of Irrelevant Alternatives (IIA) assumption that underlies the multinomial analysis.

Data formatting depends on the software and experimental design. The R software used in the [implementation explained here](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/multinomial-logistic-regression/) can accept as an outcome either a matrix with columns including the *numbers* of each category choice for a combination of predictor values, or a categorical outcome (`strategy`) with `timesChosen` for each particular combination of predictors as case weights. You can't just use `prob` as the outcome as you seem to suggest in the question, as a 10% probability is a lot more reliable if it's based on 1000 cases rather than 10 cases. Somehow the software needs to have information about the number of cases.

You will need to include `subject` in some form in the model, to account for correlations within individuals in their choices. How best to do that would depend on details of your overall experimental design.